# Get WPF Application Root Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf

I'm trying to get the application root directory but all I can find are samples that gives the directory that includes the bin directory. I want to get just the application directory. Below is what I want to retrieve

`c:\\project\myproject`

but what I'm getting is

`c:\\project\myproject\bin\debug`

I want to remove `bin\debug` how do I do this in C# wpf?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If at all, this is meaningful only on your development machine. In the deployed app, you only have the content which is now in bin\Release. If you need additional files there, set their "copy to output" attribute to True.

Comment: @KlausGütter I'm currently using MSAccess for my db and I want to get the Application root as I have placed my DB in the same as the root directory of the application. How do I get that path?

Comment: As I said: what you call "root directory" is meaningful only on your development machine. Even worse: in production the location of your app will (should) not be writable. You could make the path of your db a configuration option. Or put it in %localappdata%.

Comment: The reason is my WPF form will only be installed in a single computer. There will be multiple clients that will use this application and per computer will have it's own DB installed. So since this will be deployed to different computer we don't want to give trouble to the user to allocate a directory to where the DB should be placed. So we thought of adding it to the project directory itself

Answer (score 1):

In production the location of your app will (should) not be writable. So either make this somehow configurable, or define a fixed location, and in App startup, check if the directory and database is present - and if not, create it.

e.g.

```
var dataDir = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
    "MyCompany", "MyApp");
if (!Directory.Exists(dataDir)) 
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dataDir);
}
var databaseFile = Path.Combine(dataDir, "MyDb.mdb");
if (!File.Exists(databaseFile )) 
{
    // create database
}
```